# regex for "{constanttext}variationoftext COUL ahve any sort of cahratcers and pattern{/constanttext}"

Tags: php, regex

how would I createa regex for PHP preg_match_all when this pattern of text is being searched for:

```
{constanttext}Text with nay format and pattern or URLs.com http 3420134r09ujdmak   {/constanttext}
```

In paragraphs like this

...y. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It  {constanttext}Text with nay format and pattern or URLs.com http 3420134r09ujdmak   {/constanttext} y. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It h...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the "constanttext" portions are actually part of the text example. In that case, something like the following would work. It matches any characters in between an opening and closing {constanttext} field. If you want to test it, as well as modify it for slightly different variations, you can try a tool like regexr.com.

```
{constanttext}(.+){/constanttext}
```